# Parse JSON in PowerShell SELECT

Tags: json, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to list all my Azure VMs with their sizes using a powershell command. 
Problem is that the `HardwareProfile` property returns a JSON object, that I would like to parse and use only the `vmSize` property value of that object.

So I'm running this command:

```
Get-AzureRmVM
```

Which gives me this:

```
ResourceGroupName        : TESTRG
...
Name                     : ubuntu-server
...
HardwareProfile          : {
                             "vmSize": "Standard_DS2"
                           }
...
```

**NOTE** the JSON in the `HarwareProfile` value.

What I want to do is:

```
Get-AzureRmVM | Select ResourceGroupName, Name, HardwareProfileText `
              | Out-Gridview -PassThru
```

Which works - only, I would like to get rid of the JSON notation in the HardwareProfileText. Using `Format-Table` looks like so:

```
ResourceGroupName Name          HardwareProfileText
----------------- ----          -------------------
TESTRG            ubuntu-server {...
```

So the question is: how can I get only the value of `vmSize` in this table ? Can I sneak `ConvertFrom-Json` in somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you use the select-expression directly and convert the json-string into an object? So you can use it later in your pipeline.

Something like :

```
select @{Name="VMSize";Expression={($_|ConvertFrom-Json).vmSize}};
```

Given your json as a text in a file (for a simple-test):

```
(Get-Content -raw C:\tmp\test.json)|select @{Name="VMSize";Expression={($_|ConvertFrom-Json).vmSize}};
```

This will give you a property with only the VmSize. You can combine the expression select with normal properties as well, or multiple expressions and then continue to pass it down the pipeline if you want to filter on additional criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the get-azureRmVm function but it works just fine with the property InstanceSize instead of HardwareProfileText.

```
Import-Module 'Azure'
Get-AzureVM | Select ResourceGroupName, Name, InstanceSize `
          | Out-Gridview -PassThru
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riyhn.png)

Comment: All the *Rm* functions are from the 'new' ResourceManager model functions - I'll check whether the interface is different from the 'classic' / ASM model.